# Flink Cassandra Time out Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, cassandra-2.1

I am working on Kafka Flink Cassandra Sink. Flink code is working fine for almost 4 hours. After that, I got an exception.

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Flink but to Cassandra: your are probably writing too fast in Cassandra. Check your amount of RAM allocated to Cassandra, the number of CPU, ....

Answer (score 0):

C* is not responding to client possibly because

- C* is doing GC; you can check gc.log if you have it enabled. C* may also has high CPU whiling performing GC
- If disk write throughput could not keep up with incoming data. You may see commit log piling up. In normal cases, commit log should be recycled once the data is flushed to disk.

In addition, I would suggest to check your settings to RF# and consistency level to your write / read query. If there is another replica available (RF = 2+), you could have a chance to retrieve the copy of data from the idling node.